# Neutral element of an Algebraic structure

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider $(\epsilon,*)$ an algebraic structure. If the neutral element of $(\epsilon,*)$ is $e$ then it is unique.

Comment: Welcome to the site. What do you mean by algebraic structure? What is your question?

Comment: If by a neutral element you mean an object $a$ such that $a\ast x=x\ast a=x$ for all $x$, then yes, there is at most one neutral element.

Comment: is a non-empty set where you can define internal composition laws such as (e, #, *)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose that $e$, $e^{´} \in \epsilon$  are the neutral elements of $(\epsilon,*)$   .  $e$ is the neutral element and $e^{´}\in \epsilon$, from the definition we have that:

1)     $e*e^{´} = e^{´}*e = e^{´}$

Also, $e^{´}$is the neutral element and $e \in \epsilon$ from the definition we have that:

2)      $e^{´}*e = e*e^{´} = e$

From 1) and 2) and transitivity of equality you follow that $e = e^{´}$
which means that is unique.

Answer (score 1):

Consider any two neutral elements $e$ and $e'$ in $(\epsilon,*)$. We know, because $e$ is a neutral element, that $e * e' = e' * e = e$. We also know, because $e'$ is a neutral element, that $e * e' = e' * e = e'$. Combining these two facts gives $e = e'$, and we conclude that the neutral element of $(\epsilon,*)$ is unique.